# Adapters not working properly with Android Widgets on Fragments (RecyclerView, ExpandableListView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, crash, fragment

I have been researching for one week and still getting nothing. When I prepare the same example I used for the MainActivity, the RecyclerView loads nothing at all when it is put on a Fragment. Already did a lot of research and found no answer.
The worst part is that one example is working and follows the same protocol (to put it some way) but the other examples are not working.

All the XML files that are supposed to exist, does... so, that's not the problem... any clues?

I am having a very similar problem with an ExpandableListView (it works on a regular activity and it is unable to load data when in a fragment)

I put this code because should be the easiest one...

```
public class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
RecyclerAdapterDroids adapter;

public RecyclerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.reciclerview_in_fragment);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapterDroids();
            //RecyclerAdapterDroids(); Inner Class
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

}





public class RecyclerAdapterDroids extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterDroids.ViewHolder>{

    private String[] droidNames = {"Beep boop beep","Twing Tweeng", "Bap Beep Bop", "Bep Beep Bite", "Boop Bing Beep"};
    private  String[] details = {"high_qualified", "stupid_friendly_lazy_bot","hard_work_doer", "strong_hyperactive","crappy_lazy_bot"};
    private  int[] images = {R.drawable.android_image_1, R.drawable.android_image_2, R.drawable.android_image_3, R.drawable.android_image_4, R.drawable.android_image_5};

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.itemName.setText(droidNames[position]);
        viewHolder.itemDetail.setText(details[position]);
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return droidNames.length;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView itemImage;
        public TextView itemName;
        public TextView itemDetail;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            itemDetail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());where are you setting this manager to recyclerView?

Comment: To the fragment, now if you check every example out there that is how they say it should be done and also seems logical to me. I already tryed other options among them: getContext(), view.getContext(), getActivity.getApplicationContext(), getActivity.getBaseContext(); furthermore, that is supposed to be right one, the context of the view you are inflating (am I wrong?)  which is where the RecyclerView actually is...

Comment: R.id.recyclerview_in_fragment is inside of R.layout.fragment_recycler

Comment: the object seems to be "properly" inflated, but the control doesn't display anything. If I use the adapter to .notify(); the app just crashes.

Comment: Also, if you have a working example, that would make me happy as well. I have been looking and trying examples but they just don't work. They work on Activities but not in Fragments.

Comment: you need to set recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager); if you don't call this function then recycler view won't work

Comment: thanks, that was it

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the layout manager to your recycler view which is why it is not showing up.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

This should fix it.